# How to use a given-when 'OR' in perl?

Tags: perl

I'm pretty new in Given-When statement in perl.
I would like to get the same result for $var=0 or 2, any help?

I've tried the following but I get error.

```
given($var) {
when(0 || 2) { print "bala";}
when(1) {print "blabla";}
default {print "default";}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```
given($var) {
when($_==0 || $_==2) { print "bala";}
when(1) {print "blabla";}
default {print "default";}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can shorten it up doing this:

```
given($var) {
print "bala" when [0,2];
print "blabla" when [1];
default {print "default"}
}
```

Your original didn't work because "0 || 2" always evaluates to "2"

Comment: You don't need the arrayref on the second condition.